# How to grep strings in executable

Tags: bash, grep

I would like to grep every `word` in every files (including executables and recursively) in a folder.
I already tried `strings * | grep -Hn 'word'`.
But it return:

> (standard input):32824:word
>   (standard input):84015:word
>   ...

Instead of:

> test:3:word
>   welcome.exe:15:word
>   ...

I understand that it's because of pipe that return `strings *` to `stdin`
Does anyone already face it and resolve it ?

EDIT:
Here is the result I want:

> test:3:word
>   welcome.exe:15:word
>   ...

Or something like that:

> --- test ---
>   this is a `word`
>   --- welcome.exe ---
>   `word`s are sequence of letters

With `word` in coloured as with `grep`

Comment: `For each file given, GNU strings prints the printable character sequences` so unless you redirect each `strings myfile` to a new file, it's not possible to use `strings` for that.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ This just return binary file that match but nothing else.  
@fredtantini I'm not saying that I absolutly whant `strings`, you can propose anything else. I just want to know, when `word` is found, in wich file it is (and line if possible) as it's done with `grep`

Comment: Please take a look at EDIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found it !
It's `grep word . -rHna`
Thanks @Малъ Скрылевъ